# Is Time Between Two Other Times?

Tags: php

What I want to do (for example) is change my site's logo on Wednesdays, between 8:00pm, and 2:00am. Technically 2:00am is Thursday morning. So how would I check if the current time is between 8:00pm and 2:00am on Wednesday?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, even easier :

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');
if ($current_time > strtotime('wednesday this week 8:00pm') && $current_time < strtotime('thursday this week 2:00am')) {
    // Special logo
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I can't even think myself how easy and powerful this is! But I made a mistake: with no week specified, the following Wednesday is returned. That's unfortunate to check if the current time more recent... I added 'this week' to fix that.

Comment: I was going to take this approach, but I was 100% sure strtotime() would parse the days correctly. For instance, if it is Thursday, how does it decide that "Thursday" means today, and not next Thursday?

Comment: @Savageman: not so sexy solution now, but definitely more readable than code with 4 `date` comparisons.

Comment: @Savagement - I see you answered my question just a moment before I asked it haha

Comment: Yeah, not so sexy now. Still magic! Note that you can place "this week" at the beginning or at the end too.

Comment: Thanks Savageman and zerkms. Both work just fine. I'm going with Savageman's solution, as it looks a bit cleaner, and a bit of profiling shows it's faster.

Comment: what if the time is in 24 Hours format, say from 21:00:00 to 06:00:00 ? I believe that will give error as 21:00:00 will give a greater value using strtotime then 06:00:00

Comment: No, because strtotime() returns timestamps.

Answer (score 7):

Replace `strtotime(...)` stuff with `time()` to deal with current time.

```
$date = strtotime('2011-03-24 01:00:00');

if ((date('w', $date) == 3 && date('H', $date) >= 20) ||
    (date('w', $date) == 4 && date('H', $date) <= 1)) {
    echo "it's time to change logo";
} else {
    echo 'hello world';
}
```