# If statement if current hour is within specific time block

Tags: php, wordpress, date, if-statement, time

What im attempting to do is check if the current hour is within a specific time block that is different for most days of the week. I have attempted this about 6 different ways and it will do the else once and never again im completely stumped so i thought i'd ask the hive's help.

Here's what i've currently got.

```
    /**
     * Simple Array Storing the times to block on each day
     */
    $nonNewDay = array(
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '11:00 am'
        ),
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '11:00 am'
        ),
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '11:00 am'
        ),
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '11:00 am'
        ),
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '11:00 am'
        ),
        // Weekends
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '1:00 pm'
        ),
        array(
            '2:00 am',
            '12:00 pm'
        ),
    );

    // Get Current weekday and time;
    $weekday = date('w');
    $date = date('m-d-Y');
    $time = date('g:00 a', strtotime('now'));

    echo $date;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $time;
    echo '<br />';

    /**
     * Were Attempting to block out all time blocks that are NOT "New Day Programming"
     * Which currently are:
     * Mon - Fri 11:00 am - 2:00 am
     * Sat, Sun 2:00 am - 1PM
     */

    if (strtotime($date . ' ' . $time) <= strtotime($date . ' ' . $nonNewDay[$weekday - 1][0]) && strtotime($date . ' ' . $time) >= strtotime($date . ' ' . $nonNewDay[$weekday - 1][1])) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should probably do the work for you:

```
$current_date = strtotime(date("g:00 a"));
$value = $nonNewDay[date('N')-1];
// for php < 5.1, I think this one will do the work:
// $value = $nonNewDay[(date('w') == 0 ? 6 : date('N')-1)];
if ((strtotime($value[0]) <= $current_date) && ($current_date < strtotime($value[1]))) {
    die('Blocked');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413505/is-time-between-two-other-times)

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');
if ($current_time > strtotime('wednesday this week 8:00pm') && $current_time <    
    strtotime('thursday this week 2:00am')) {
// do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Would that work with the differing times seen in the array above? without having multiple if else's?

Comment: No sorry you would need to write multiple if statements, or multiple or statements. The way you wish to do it would be far cleaner.

Comment: you could just use a for loop to loop through the array and replace the day and time with your values.